# Verify the correct usage of Spring boot filter

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a filter which is used to validate the license of a ReactJS/Spring boot application:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class LicenseFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private LicenseController licenseController;

    @Autowired
    public LicenseFilter(LicenseController licenseController) {
        this.licenseController = licenseController;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            if (licenseController.isLicenseValid()) {
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(200);
            } else {
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("An error occurred while validating license in the filter", e);
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

The above filter works as expected I just want to verify that the usage is correct. Especially the line `filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse)`.

FYI: There is another filter after the LicenseFilter which is used to validate authentication

Thanks

UPDATE:

Earlier the above filter used to look like this:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class LicenseFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private LicenseController licenseController;

    @Autowired
    public LicenseFilter(LicenseController licenseController) {
        this.licenseController = licenseController;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            if (licenseController.isLicenseValid()) {
                filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse); // change is here
            } else {
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("An error occurred while validating license in the filter", e);
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
        }
    }
}
```

When the filter was implemented like this it did not work as expected. The license is validated properly but the UI shows an empty screen instead of redirecting to login page (UI redirects to login page when a 401 is received)

Comment: Have you tried it? (Note that your code will set a status, then unconditionally hand the request to the regular chain, which will set its own status and ignore what you said.) Make sure you understand the Filter design pattern.

Comment: If your filter check sth right, let next filter doFilter. otherwise, stop the filterChain.

Just like :
`public void doFilter(req, res) {
   if (checkSomeError) {
      //set response status and error message.
   } else {
      filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
   }
}`

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- with the implementation like this, the application works as expected. Could you please check the update in my question

Comment: @meng could you please check the update in my question if that is the correct implementation?

Comment: Mostly correct. just change `httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);` to `httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Your error msg.");` And more, you can refer to `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter#doFilterInternal()`